How does toISOstring() command work in react?
In my React application, I have a form with two question. When i chose starttime now and i chose duration 6 the POST request is supposed to send to my database starttime ( current time ) and endtime ( current time + 6 hours ). However, the starttime and the endtime sent to my database are only 4 hours apart instead of 6. I suspect this is a problem related with timezone specification. How can i resolve this issue ? Should i not use toISOstring() and try another approach ?
Below is the source code for form. Could you please review it to see if there is an error, or if the issue lies elsewhere?
const handleStarttimeChange = (event) => {
  const newStarttime = event.target.value;
  setStarttime(newStarttime);
  updateEndtime(newStarttime, duration);
};

const handleDurationChange = (event) => {
  const durationValue = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);
  setDuration(durationValue);
  console.log(durationValue, "duationValue");
  updateEndtime(starttime, durationValue);
};

const handleDateOptionChange = (event) => {
  setDateOption(event.target.value);
  const now = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 16);
  setStarttime(now);
  updateEndtime(now, duration);
};

const updateEndtime = (start, duration) => {
  if (isNaN(duration) || duration <= 0 || !start) {
    setEndtime("");
    return;
  }
  const startTime = new Date(start);
  const endTime = new Date(startTime.getTime() + duration * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  setEndtime(endTime.toISOString().slice(0, 16));
  console.log(startTime, "starttime in function update");
  console.log(endtime, "endTime in function update");
};

const postData = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (!starttime || !endtime) {
    alert("Please fill in all fields.");
    return;
  }

  axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACK_URL}/add_data`,
    data: {
      starttime: starttime,
      endtime: endtime,
    },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error.response) {
        console.log(error.response);
        console.log(error.response.status);
        console.log(error.response.headers);
      }
    });
};

return (
  <div className="formulaire">
    <form id="addDataForm" name="addDataForm">
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <RadioGroup
            row
            aria-label="date"
            name="date"
            id="date"
            value={dateOption}
            onChange={handleDateOptionChange}
          >
            <FormControlLabel
              value="now"
              control={<Radio />}
              label="Maintenant"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              value="program"
              control={<Radio />}
              label="Programmer"
            />
          </RadioGroup>

          {dateOption === "program" && (
            <TextField
              id="starttime"
              label="Start date"
              type="datetime-local"
              value={starttime}
              onChange={handleStarttimeChange}
              InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true,
              }}
              inputProps={{
                min: "2024-01-01T00:00",
                max: "2024-12-31T23:59",
              }}
            />
          )}
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <FormControl sx={{ width: "10vh" }}>
            <InputLabel id="durationlabel">Durée (heures)</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="durationlabel"
              id="duration"
              name="duration"
              label="Durée (heures)"
              value={duration}
              onChange={handleDurationChange}
              required
            >
              <MenuItem value={1}>1</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={2}>2</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={3}>3</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={4}>4</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={5}>5</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={6}>6</MenuItem>
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            variant="contained"
            className="button"
            onClick={postData}
          >
            Fermer la route
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </form>
  </div>
);


